# Detect whether a sound effect is currently playing in SimpleAudioEngine

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

I want to detect whether [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] is currently playing any effect. For Background music there is a method that gives you the information whether background music is playing:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] isBackgroundMusicPlaying];
```

Does something similar exist for sound effects? If not how else can I detect whether I am already playing an effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SimpleAudioEngine` Doesn't have a method like `isBackgroundMusicPlaying` for effects, but you can store a `BOOL` called isPlaying and use `CDSoundSource`

```
CDSoundSource* currentSound = [[CDAudioManager sharedManager] audioSourceForChannel:kASC_Right];
[currentSound load:audioFile];
currentSound.delegate = self;
currentSound.backgroundMusic = NO;
isPlaying = YES;
[currentSound play];
```

Then implement the callback:

```
- (void) cdAudioSourceDidFinishPlaying:(CDLongAudioSource *) audioSource {
    isPlaying = NO;
}
```

I don't know exactly if that's the correct way to initialise the `CDSoundSource` since I've stolen shamelessly the code from [this topic](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/13178) . Maybe you should take a look at the [CDAudioManager Class Reference](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.2/interface_c_d_audio_manager.html)

Hope this helps to point you in the right direction.